# No module named importlib.util while deploying to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am deploying `Django App` to Heroku. Everything is working fine BUT when i push my code into `heroku master` using `git push heroku master` then it installed all the requirements BUT at the end it shows

```
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-eh43np6w/importlib/
remote:            Complete output (11 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
remote:                import distutils.core
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 16, in <module>
remote:                from distutils.dist import Distribution
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 19, in <module>
remote:                from distutils.util import check_environ, strtobool, rfc822_escape
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/distutils/util.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:                import importlib.util
remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'
```

AND THEN

```
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to nytictactoe.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/nytictactoe.git
```

AND ALSO

```
No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.5
```

I have tried many times BUT it keep showing this error.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you included these files

```
runtime.txt
Procfile
requirements.txt
```

-runtime.txt contains your python version

-requirements.txt contains the packages you are using

-Procfile contains something beyond my knowledge so i suggest to look that in Heroku documentation

Comment: I used `Python-3.7.5`, BUT Heroku doesn't support it then i choose 3.8.5. I have created runtime.txt
I have created Procfile
I have created requirements.txt

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes use `python-3.7.10` If that does not work update your post with the **entire** build log.